# PyQT5 - QPushButton (Clicked) - not working

Tags: python, button, pyqt, pyqt5

I have problem with my code in Python 3.8 (PyQT5). I want to make simple print after button will be clicked, but nothing happens.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.uic.properties import QtCore

from FutureMeMailSender import Ui_FutureMeMail

class FutureMeMail(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, MailSender):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FutureMeMail, self).__init__()
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.

        self.ui.pushButtonSendMail.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.receiver_mail = self.ui.lineEditMail.text()

        self.ui = Ui_FutureMeMail()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.show()

    def clicked(self):
        print("PushButtonAction -- Hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QDialog()
    ui = Ui_FutureMeMail()
    ui.setupUi(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What is the `MailSender` used in the class inheritance? In your code there's no trace of it, maybe you meant `Ui_FutureMeMail`?

Answer (score 1):

`clicked` is already an attribute of the object, if you name this function like this you'll shadow it. Use `on_click` for example instead.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.uic.properties import QtCore

from FutureMeMailSender import Ui_FutureMeMail

class FutureMeMail(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, MailSender):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FutureMeMail, self).__init__()
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.

        self.ui.pushButtonSendMail.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.receiver_mail = self.ui.lineEditMail.text()

        self.ui = Ui_FutureMeMail()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.show()

    def on_click(self):
        print("PushButtonAction -- Hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QDialog()
    ui = Ui_FutureMeMail()
    ui.setupUi(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: yes, maybe, but if I`ll change name of function to "przycisk" (in Polish - button) also nothing is happening

Comment: @ps19 Please accept answer if it helped you — button ✅ near answer.

Comment: @ps19 I dont suggest use not english word in code. It may make code unreadable.

Comment: not English word only for test, still not working so, it wasn`t problem with that word

Comment: @ps19 I guess your problem is caused by content of module FutureMeMailSender. Has MailSender the function clicked ?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica `clicked` is not an attribute of QMainWindow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `self.ui` object,

and then do:

```
self.ui.pushButtonSendMail.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.uic.properties import QtCore

from FutureMeMailSender import Ui_FutureMeMail

class FutureMeMail(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):     # ??? , MailSender):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FutureMeMail, self).__init__()
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.

        self.ui = Ui_FutureMeMail()                                   # +++
        self.ui.setupUi(self)                                         # +++

        self.ui.pushButtonSendMail.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.receiver_mail = self.ui.lineEditMail.text()

# ---        self.ui = Ui_FutureMeMail()
# ---        self.ui.setupUi(self)

#        self.show()

    def clicked(self):
        print("PushButtonAction -- Hello")
        self.ui.lineEditMail.setText('Hello PyQt5')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#    window = QDialog()
#    ui = Ui_FutureMeMail()
#    ui.setupUi(window)
#    window.show()

    w = FutureMeMail()                                  # +++
    w.show()                                            # +++        

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```